# Use multiple options with the IF() function

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Sorry if this has been covered — I can't find a solution that works. I'm trying to automatically calculate credit card fees depending on the method chosen in cell BG3:

```
=IF(BG3="Web Stripe",((BE3+BF3)*0.014)+0.2, 0,IF(BG3="Web Stripe Int",((BE3+BF3)*0.029)+0.2, 0,))
```

Basically, with Stripe I get charged 1.4%+20p for European card transactions and 2.9%+20p for non-European cards (which I'm calling 'Int').

Comment: It's my first post. Have I annoyed you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the cell the formula is in gives you the error (Wrong number of arguments). Try this:

```
=IF(BG3="Web Stripe",((BE3+BF3)*0.014)+0.2,IF(BG3="Web Stripe Int",((BE3+BF3)*0.029)+0.2, 0))
```

Comment: That works perfectly now. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Could you please approve the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer? Thanks.